# cannot using attach() method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following relations set up:

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Note::class);
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

and pivot table like this:

```
Schema::create('note_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('note_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('note_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('notes')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

now, i used Attach() method:

```
$note->tags()->attach($tagsIds);
```

but that doesn't work and I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>    Cannot instantiate interface phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've imported the wrong class that corresponds to **Tag::class**.

It should probably be something like this:

> use App\Tag;

instead of:

> use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tag;